# Drawing SVG from C#

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, svg

I want to create a UserControl that consists of a div. Inside the div would be a number of SVG rendered boxes.  How many boxes and their relative positions would be determined from data.

The data would be in the form of a List of class Box where Box is as follows:

```
 public class SVGBox
 {
    public int x { get; set; }  // x coordinate of a corner
    public int y { get; set; }  // x coordinate of same corner
    public int l { get; set; }  // length
    public int h { get; set; }  // height
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string uniqueKey { get; set; }

    public SVGBox (int X, int Y, int H, int W, string Text, string Key )
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        h = H;
        w = W;
        text = Text;
        uniqueKey = Key;
    }
 }
```

I have an example I found on the 'Net for rendering SVG from C#, but it involves writing out the entire HTML page with specific references in the DOCTYPE. How do I do this inside a User Control?

Comment: I would suggest trying to use Html5 and JavaScript if possible.

Comment: I was thinking that with Html5, the boxes aren't individual elements. The next step after I get this to draw is to get OnClick to do something with the unique key. What reasons are there to favor Html5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, once I got the right start, not too bad.

In the ascx, I simply added an asp:Literal. And here's the code behind:

```
public partial class Controls_SVGTest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public List<SVGBox> data { get; set; }

    const string HeaderText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> <svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" " +
                                "xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" height=\"{0}\" width=\"{1}\" >";

    const string BoxSVG = "<rect x=\"{0}\" y=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" width=\"{3}\" rx=\"2\" fill=\"{4}\" stroke=\"#707070\" />";
    const string Footer = "</svg>";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSVG();
    }

    public void LoadSVG()
    {
        Literal1.Text = String.Format(HeaderText, Height.ToString(), Width.ToString());
        foreach (SVGBox s in data)
        {
            Literal1.Text += String.Format(BoxSVG, s.x, s.y, s.h, s.w, s.Color);
        }
        Literal1.Text += Footer;
    }

}
```